# Is there an issue with the el-input element im using because i gets the on-icon-click error

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

```html
<el-input
  type="password"
  v-model="data.password"
  prefix-icon="el-icon-lock"
  suffix-icon="el-icon-view"
  :on-icon-click="show"
></el-input>
```

I tried the above code but getting:

> migrating.js?696e:49 [Element Migrating][ElInput][Attribute]: on-icon-click is removed.

May I know my mistake? How to specify on-click is for which icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attribute was removed in [Release 2.0.0 Carbon](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/releases/tag/v2.0.0)

Note:
Removed `on-icon-click` attribute and click event. Now to add click handler on icons, please use named slots.

The code is modified as follows

```
<el-input
  type="password"
  v-model="data.password"
>
  <i slot="prefix" class="el-icon-lock" @click="show"></i>
  <i slot="suffix" class="el-icon-view" @click="show"></i>
</el-input>
```

Comment: Also, in order to keep the icon(s) vertically centered inside the input element, you might have to include *el-input__icon* class in the icon element tag too, like `<i slot="prefix" class="el-input__icon el-icon-lock" @click="show"></i>`